# how to cache a query result in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

my controller's methods uses the same query result to return various result (Jsonresult,actionresult)
is there a way to cache the result in memory so that there is only one trip to data base for all controller methods so instead of executing the query the methods uses the result in cache

the variable that i want to cache is  var x = from cus in db.BIOBillPh( )

```
    public ActionResult BillPhp(string CodePays)
    {
        var x = from cus in db.BIOBillPh( )

                select cus;
        return PartialView(x);

    }


    public JsonResult PaysBU(string  Pays)
    {


        var x = from cus in db.BIOBillPh()
                select cus;
        return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: There are any number of cache strategies available to you.  What have you already tried so far?

Comment: i used outputcaching, but the problem is that i want the methods to share the same data result so that the query is executed only once

Comment: You have some more reading to do on the lifetime of cache strategies.  The output cache is limited to a request/response stream.

Answer (score 1):

Controller instances are created on every call so not really. You could create an static interim object within your controller that would have some life span before refreshing db calls. Is this an action that's called with high frequency? The marginal, if any reduction in overhead might not be worth your time.

Comment: it's possible to create a static object with a timer to refresh the data ?? if yes how can i do it please ??